# How to get 3D point cloud from a streaming 3D data?

Tags: 3d, kinect

I am using Kinect to capture 3D data, it contains 2 seperate streams RGB and depth stream.

By using some else' (Oliver Kreylos, http://idav.ucdavis.edu/~okreylos/ResDev/Kinect/index.html) program I managed to get a reconstructed 3D view. I now want to capture 3D point cloud for a still frame from this.

Any idea on how can I get 3D point cloud?

Answer (score 0):

A 3D point cloud is simply a view of the depth stream.
The depth stream information that comes from the Kinect device is an array of integers that is 640x480 large.
All you need to do is to iterate through this depth stream, and plot the points into a 3D view as follows:
depth[0,0] with value 3000 gives you x=0, y=0, z=3000.
depth[640, 480] with value 2500 gives you x=640, y=480, z=2500.
Have fun.